# Action only happens after second button press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a button called signOut which changes a context value and signs a user out of my web app, however it seems to be only performing these changes after I click the button for a second time.

Initially, I thought it was because the process was async and so the header component was being rendered before the context has changed, however (and I know its dodgy) to check this I added a setTimeout and only navigated to the home page after 2 seconds which still didn't fix it.

```
    const signOut = () => {
        setUserDetails({"displayName":""})
        auth.signOut().then(() => {
            console.log(userDetails)
            navigate("/")
        })
    }
```

Here is the code I call onClick

Here is the code for the header (which should rerender after userDetails is updated)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(userDetails.displayName)
        if (userDetails.displayName !== "") {
            setLoginUser(userDetails.displayName)
            setLoginUserPath("/settings")
        } else {
            setLoginUser("Log in")
            setLoginUserPath("/login")            
        }
    }, [userDetails.displayName])
```

here is the context:

```
  const userDetails = createContext({
    userDetails: {"displayName":""},
    setUserDetails: (input) => {}
  });
```

This is what happens when I click the sign out button the first time
[image]

This is what happens the second time I click the same button (note header.js now returns an empty string rather than "Toby")
[image]

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I haven't been able to find anything too similar (although I feel as though its going to have a really simple answer that Ive massively overlooked).

PS; codefiles dumped as it was suggested I provided more context (I'm relatively new to javascript so don't be too judgy please :) )

App.js (which is the main component which renders everything)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import { Outlet, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Header from './Header'
import Showing from './Showing'
import MovieContext from '../contexts/Movies.js'
import UserDetails from '../contexts/userDetails'
import loginInputContext from '../contexts/InputInfo'
import currentTicket from '../contexts/currentTicket'
import timeslotsContext from '../contexts/timeslots'
import database, {auth} from './Firebase.js'
import SyncLoader from 'react-spinners/SyncLoader'
import Background from './background'


const App = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('idle')
  const [input, setInput] = useState({"email":"", "password":"", "phone":"", "name":""})
  const [ticketDetails, setTicketDetails] = useState({"movieID":"0", "time":"0", "seating":"0", "food":null, "foodOption":"0", "foodTime":"0"})
  const [timeslots, setTimeslots] = useState({1:{"date":"0", "movie":"1", "seating":"test"}})
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({"displayName":""})
  const movies = useRef([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const updatedMovies = []
    updateUser()

    database.ref('movies').once("value", (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach(snap => {
        updatedMovies.push(snap.val())
      })
      movies.current = updatedMovies
      setStatus("resolved")
    })

  },[userDetails.displayName])

  const updateUser = () => {
    const user = auth.currentUser
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      if (userDetails.displayName !== user.displayName) {
        setUserDetails({"displayName":user.displayName})
      }
    } else if (auth.currentUser === null && userDetails.displayName !== "") {
      setUserDetails({"displayName":""})
    }
  }

  if (status === 'idle') {
    return(
      <div className="flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center">
        <Background />
        <SyncLoader color="#2B7A78"/>
      </div>
      )
  }
  else if (status === 'resolved') {
    updateUser()
    return (
      <UserDetails.Provider value={{userDetails, setUserDetails}}>
      <MovieContext.Provider value={movies.current}>
      <currentTicket.Provider value={{ticketDetails, setTicketDetails}}> 
      <timeslotsContext.Provider value={{timeslots, setTimeslots}}>
        <div className="">
          <div className="fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 z-50">
            <Header/>
          </div>

          <div className="h-screen w-full justify-center pt-40 p-20 flex">
            <loginInputContext.Provider value={{input, setInput}}>
              <Outlet/>
            </loginInputContext.Provider>
          </div>

          <div className="flex" >
            {/* This is temp for getting showing to work */}
            <Routes> 
              <Route path="/" element={<Showing/>} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
          <Background/>
        </div>
      </timeslotsContext.Provider>
      </currentTicket.Provider>
      </MovieContext.Provider>
      </UserDetails.Provider>
  )}
}

export default App
```

Header.js (I just use this an example as it is very clear that the text does not update (changes from users name to login))

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import logo from './Images/logo.svg'
import userDetailsContext from '../contexts/userDetails'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import {auth} from './Firebase.js'

const Header = () => {
    const hidden = "hidden"
    const shown = "text-sm text-center text-theme-white font-light font-sans py-2"
    const {userDetails} = useContext(userDetailsContext)
    const [loginUser, setLoginUser] = useState("")
    const [loginUserPath, setLoginUserPath] = useState("")
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(hidden)

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (showMenu === hidden) {
            setShowMenu(shown)
        } else {
            setShowMenu(hidden)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(userDetails.displayName)
        if (userDetails.displayName !== "") {
            setLoginUser(userDetails.displayName)
            setLoginUserPath("/settings")
        } else {
            setLoginUser("Log in")
            setLoginUserPath("/login")            
        }
    }, [userDetails.displayName])

    return (

        {/* Header nav */},

        <nav className="bg-gradient-to-r from-theme-dark to-theme">
            <div className="flex justify-between px-5 font-sans font-light text-sm">

                {/* Logo */}

                <div className="text-theme-white font-bold py-3">
                    <Link to="/" className="flex gap-x-5 items-center">
                        <img src={logo} alt="Logo" className=""/>
                        <span>Apollo</span>
                    </Link>
                </div>

                {/* Navigation */}

                <div className="hidden sm:flex gap-x-7 text-theme-white items-center">
                    <Link to="/" className="py-3 hover:text-theme-black">Home</Link>
                    <Link to="/bookings" className="py-3 hover:text-theme-black">My Bookings</Link>
                    <Link to={loginUserPath} className="py-3 hover:text-theme-black">{loginUser}</Link>
                    <Link to="/book/movie" className="bg-theme-light rounded-2xl text-theme-black py-3 px-3 hover:bg-theme-black hover:text-theme-white transition duration-150">Make Booking</Link>
                </div>

                <div className="sm:hidden flex items-center gap-x-7">
                <Link to="/book/movie" className="bg-theme-light rounded-2xl text-theme-black py-3 px-3 hover:bg-theme-black hover:text-theme-white transition duration-150">Make Booking</Link>
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="#FEFFFF">
                            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={showMenu}>
                <Link to="/" onClick={handleClick} className="block hover:bg-theme-light hover:text-theme-black py-2 px-2">Home</Link>
                <Link to="/bookings" onClick={handleClick} className="block hover:bg-theme-light hover:text-theme-black py-2 px-2">My Bookings</Link>
                <Link to={loginUserPath} onClick={handleClick} className="block hover:bg-theme-light hover:text-theme-black py-2 px-2">{loginUser}</Link>
            </div>
        </nav>


    )

}

export default Header
```

And finally, Settings.js where the sign out actually occurs:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import {auth} from './Firebase.js'
import userDetailsContext from '../contexts/userDetails'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router'


const Settings = (props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const {userDetails, setUserDetails} = useContext(userDetailsContext)

    //Stupid design - needs cleaning up 
    //Please tell me if this code is in any sort of final build, I will hate myself forever
    const signOut = () => {
        setUserDetails({"displayName":""})
        auth.signOut().then(() => {
            console.log(userDetails)
            navigate("/")
        })
    }


    return (
        <div className="h-full w-full z-10 flex justify-center items-center">
            <div className="bg-theme-white h-full w-full text-sm md:text-2xl lg:text-4xl lg:w-2/5 font-sans font-light text-theme-black text-center z-10 rounded-lg flex justify-between flex-col py-10">
                <div className="flex md:gap-x-5 px-10 mb-2 justify-center items-center">Settings</div>
                <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
                <div>
                    <span>name: </span>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )  
}


export default Settings
```

Comment: It's difficult to say what any issue is without the greater context of the component/app code in which this code is running. Can you update to provide a more complete and comprehensive code example? Can you try also creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated with a significant more amount of code, I can give you a working codesandbox demo in a couple of hours if you still want that